# ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring-mvc

New to Spring mvc, i am trying to display custom error messages using "ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" from properties file but still i am not able to get custom messages what i am getting is spring default messages.

**My Controller Class:-**

```
public class Controller1 {

    @InitBinder
    public void initMethod(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "name", new Customproperty());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/frontend/getdetails.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getStudentsData(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("input");
            return model;
        }

        else {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("output");
            return model;
        }

    }
```

**My model class:-**
where size variable is validated.

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    @Size(min = 5, max = 15)
    private String address;
    private String hobby;
    private String email;
    }
```

**Spring Xml file:-**

```
<bean id="messages"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/errormessages"></property>
    </bean>
```

**Property file**(/SpringLearning_9dec/WebContent/WEB-INF/errormessages.properties):-

```
Size.student.address = address should be with in 44 to 44 characters.
```

PFA screen shot also:-[program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpyCx.png)

Comment: By default, your properties files should be under the `src/main/resources` folder. Try to put your file in the resources package and modify `property` tag like this, `<property name="basename" value="errormessages"></property>`.

Comment: Tried the above, still not able to get custom message.

Comment: Spring will validate the criteria,  in this case,  @Size(min = 5, max = 15)
private String address; in model class, if found invalid then spring will automatically search for the property "annotation.object.property" key in property file, i am not fetching the property manually.

Comment: Yes, I have figured that out. Missed that part.

Comment: Could you please try to change the id of bean for `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` from `messages` to `messageSource`.

Comment: It worked, can u tell me wht was the issue here, "id" is just a unique identifier, and when i don't specify any id still it gave me default spring error message??

Comment: glad it worked, I've tried to figure out the reason. If this solved your problem, please accept the answer as accepted. For default messages, Spring uses the annotation and the boundary parameters for the property. As Spring could not find the bean with `messageSource` id, it used default message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'm not sure but there seems to be the issue with the `id` which is used for `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` property. As explained in the docs for [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html), it is an implementation of [public interface MessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html). So both of its implementation classes, `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and `ResourceBundleMessageSource` should have an id as same as the interface `messageSource`.

I think while looking for the implementation of interface `MessageSource` Spring looks for the bean with id `messageSource` with implementation class either `ResourceBundleMessageSource` or `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.